# Change of variables of inverse Jacobi multiplier

Tags: calculus

I have got an Inverse Jacobi multiplier $$M=x^{3}z-3(1+kz)4-2\frac{c}{k}$$ and I have a change of variable $$Z=\frac{z(1+kz)c}{3k}-\frac{2}{3}$$ and I want to use this theorem: Let $M$ be an inverse Jacobi multiplier. If the change of coordinates $Y=Y(Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3})=G(x,y,z)$ introduced the $W(Y)=(MοG-1)(Y)\det(DG(G-1(Y)))$, to find inverse Jacobi multiplier, but I could not do that, Please could you help me?

Regards